# Hibernate soft delete sets foreign key to null

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have 2 entities like this:

```
@SQLDelete(sql = "UPDATE parent_table SET deleted = true WHERE id = ?")
public class Parent {
 private boolean deleted;

 @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
 @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
 private List<Child> children;

// other stuff
}

@SQLDelete(sql = "UPDATE child_table SET deleted = true WHERE id = ?")
public class Child {
 private boolean deleted;
 // stuff
}
```

As you can see, its a unidirectional @OneToMany mapping and both entities use soft delete with the `@SQLDelete` annotation.
I'm trying to soft delete the parent and in turn want the child to be soft deleted as well.

When I try to soft delete , it sets the `deleted` flag to true in both tables and that's what I want.
However, the `parent_id` in the `child_table` is set to `null` when I perform the delete. Why is this happening and how can I stop this ?

The delete operation :

```
Parent parent= entityManager.find(Parent.class, id);
entityManager.remove(parent);
```

Comment: The parent is being deleted it's the way it should be no? Look for cascade delete.

Comment: The delete flag is set and that's exactly what I want. But hibernate destroys the parent-child relationship as well, by setting the foreign key in `child_table` to `null` .

Comment: Destroying the parent-child relationship when cascading the delete operation from the parent to privately owned children is only logical, and Hibernate does not know (or care) what the query from `@SQLDelete` does. For this reason, I strongly suspect that what you're asking is impossible.

Comment: "As you can see, its a unidirectional @OneToOne mapping". Well I can't see that as the code suggests `@OneToMany`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to:

1. Replace `@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)` with `@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)`.
2. Add `nullable = false` to `@JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")` annotation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if what you want is possible, but you could try adding this to your mapping:

```
@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.NO_ACTION)
```

Maybe with this Hibernate won't change the relationship.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you can turn off cascade delete and manually delete the children