# Disable Foreign Key Derefrencing Hibernate

Tags: database, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

**Hibernate de-references foreign keys on delete in a few cases**

When defining a OneToMany relationship in Hibernate (using annotations). On the mapping side (Many side), I use id columns rather than entities to define such mapping. That is mainly because there is a list of such entities on the 'One' side. Defining the properties as such helps avoid circular dependencies.

In the example below, the Listing entity holds the reference to the MainListing through the mainListingId column. While, the MainListing entity contains a collection of Listing entities.

When it comes to deleting entities, I apply soft deletes on the db level. Each table has a deleted column (bool) to indicate whether a row is deleted or not. Therefore, there is no requirement to completely remove entries on delete from the db.

The issue that I am running into is related to the delete process in hibernate. The setup defined above works fine with other entity relations setup. However, in the use case defined above, on execution of a delete, an update statement that sets `fk_id=null` gets executed, causing the entries to be de-referenced. In this example, the following happens `mainListingId=null`, thus breaking the link between a Listing and a MainListing. This is not the intended behavior, as I would still like to be able to retrieve the MainListing entity and all it's associated Listings after deletion.

**Note:** This only happens in the following cases
- @OneToMany relations
- Id column references rather than entity (code snippet below)

```
@Entity
@SQLDelete(sql = "update main_listing set deleted=1 where id=?")
MainListing { 
    ...
    @OneToMany(cascade = [CascadeType.ALL], fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "main_listing_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @Where(clause = "deleted=false")
    var listings: List<Listing> = emptyList(),
    ...
}

@Entity
@SQLDelete(sql = "update listing set deleted=1 where id=?")
Listing {
    ...
    @Column(name = "main_listing_id", updatable = false)
    var mainListingId: Long? = null,
    ...
}
```

Comment: Your question is rather unclear. In order to increase your chances of getting an appropriate answer, plase edit your question to provide an [mcve] and explain what expected vs. observed behaviour is.

Comment: So softDelete actually works but you don't want child entities to lose reference to the softly deleted entity? Did you see this: [Hibernate soft delete sets foreign key to null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46849848/hibernate-soft-delete-sets-foreign-key-to-null) ?

Comment: @Selaron yes, similar issue but doesn't seem to be resolved

Comment: Do you use bytecode enhanced entities with `hibernate.enhancer.enableAssociationManagement`?

Comment: @Selaron I don't use bytecode enhanced entities, should I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this was to add the following to the parent entity

`@JoinColumn(... nullable=false, insertable=false)`

The above serves the following purposes

- solves the de-referencing issue on delete
- does not affect the update behaviour since updatabale=true by default
- does not affect inserts since the default value of the foreign key is null on insert